# Sql Server wildcard Like Statement : How to use for data having undefined Length

Tags: sql-server

I have URL data in a table like this(Showing only one row i have many more in table)

```
abc/portfolio/12/strategy
abc/portfolio/15/strategy
abc/portfolio/1/strategy
```

The data is in four part separated with '/'.
i got a string to match with this data, either i got a same string to match or if i can get "*" at any part of data if i don't need to match the particular part Like

```
abc/portfolio/*/strategy
```

if i get this string to match i don't have to match the '*' part,rest i need to match with the data. i need to match `abc/portfolio/%` with i need to Match `%/strategy` in a single column data.

i don't know how to do it with wildcards also as in data its not define that what is the length of a particular part.

As well as if i got two '**' then i need to match only intial Part of Data 
Like if i get data to match `abc/**/12/strategy`then i only need to match `abc\%` in data.
Example:

```
Select Url_data from schema1.table1
where 
url_data Like 'abc/portfolio/*/strategy'
```

here i need the "*" to work like, ignore the data in that particular Part. 
outcome expected is :

```
abc/portfolio/12/strategy
abc/portfolio/15/strategy
abc/portfolio/1/strategy
```

Comment: where (myUrl like 'abc/portfolio/%' AND myUrl like '%/strategy')

Comment: But i will get a full string Like "abc/**/12/strategy"  how i will divide this in two part ? there may be possibilities of dividing data in three part.?

Comment: maybe more sample data and expected outcome would help us understand your question better

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @v varchar(100) = 'abc/portfolio/*/strategy'

Select Url_data from schema1.table1 where  url_data Like
replace(
  case 
      when charindex('**',@v) > 0 then left(@v, charindex('**',@v))   
      else @v
  end
  ,'*','%')
```

This will replace the `*` by `%` if only one `*` is in the variable `@v` or truncate the text after `**` and replace `**` it by `%`.

```
declare @v varchar(100) = 'abc/portfolio/*/strategy' -> abc/portfolio/%/strategy
declare @v varchar(100) = 'abc/portfolio/**/strategy' --> abc/portfolio/%
```

Comment: But i will get a full string Like "abc/**/12/strategy" how i will divide this in two part ? there may be possibilities of dividing data in three part.?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "*" you can use '%' as follows

```
Select Url_data from schema1.table1
where 
url_data Like 'abc/portfolio/%/strategy'
```